# (AndroidX) uses or overrides a deprecated API Problem in Database

Tags: android, android-studio, mvvm, deprecated, androidx

I have a Warring in my project and I'm using MVVM (AndroidX) but I have this warring message:

```
C:\Users\meste\AndroidStudioProjects\Dacterzo\app\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\notaf\dacterzo\XAListDatabase_Impl.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

- this class in this directory "\app\build\generated\source\apt\debug\" is auto generated Android Studio